Guide to develop / edit ubuntu 24.04 GUI (file dialogs)
I'd like to start improve the default gnome's open/save/explore file dialogs and apps in ubuntu 24.04 including some shortcuts that are annoyingly don't exist (like ctrl+l to reach the file path text box, create folder in some don't work, create file shortcuts etc...) and I'm not sure where to start from in term of relevant path's and dir that define the GUI behavior, what gui framework does it use?( I Assume gnome with gtk3?)
though I'm quite new to gtk3 I still developed some apps with qt5 and would like to just edit a few annoying things with the dialog windows that interrupt my workflow between windows and apps.
Any suggestion as of where to start, relevant dirs and paths, relevant frameworks and keywords are welcomed

This is a site of volunteers who try to answer questions about things that have failed or do not work as the OS should No one here works for the maker of Ubuntu. Not sure this is a place for this question.

I'm familiar with some of the problems in Ubuntu 24.04 you mentioned, but perhaps you're overthinking it. I wrote three bash scripts 1. Create-new-file.sh 2. Create-a-new-folder.sh 3. List-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-the-terminal.sh which I can access from the terminal with two-character aliases. That's my suggestion about where to start. If that doesn't work at un-jamming things in the Files app, I also wrote a minimalistic GUI alternative to the Files app in 24.04 in Python using tkinter.

No that's the thing the gui is a part of the work flow especially when working with images and videos and I want to smoothen it a bit by unianizing short cuts and actions like copy current selected file/files path/dir while also having control over the copy config like copy using wild card ~ or /home/user/ etc... it feels like ubuntu's file dialogs are not refined enough to a point where I can say windows did a slightly better job there so I'd like to fix it if there is no quick close to legacy you can that sumerizes it up out there

Maybe If I can remake or use the template of a gtk ui I'll code, and be able to port file dialogs requests from xdg apps like chrome or brave or tmux and other apps of such (which I don't know much terminology and keywords to do that in Ubuntu) I could make it work.
